# Register prototype function as callback

Tags: javascript, frontend

I've added a keydown event listener with `document.addEventListener`, and I wanted to remove it later somewhere else by calling `document.removeEventListener`.

I know this sounds quite easy, but since I'm editing some generated code, and the generator seems love prototype, so the whole bunch of code are based on prototype. Here's the simplified version:

First, I have this object say `function A() {XXX}`, I've added a listener function to the prototype:

```
A.prototype.listener = function () {console.log(this);}
```

And there's a `listen` method in the prototype,

```
A.prototype.listen = function() {
    document.addEventListener "keydown", KeyboardInputManager.prototype.listener
}
```

Finally, there's a `stopListen` method:

```
A.prototype.stopListen = function() {
    document.removeEventListener "keydown", KeyboardInputManager.prototype.listener
}
```

There are two issues here, first, even though the `stopListen` method is called, the event still got posted, and second, in my `listener` method, I wanted to call some other prototype methods of `A`, but the `this` var in it is the `document` that is passed to the listener (this is my guess, correct me if I'm wrong).

So, I'm confused how to fix this, please help me out of here!

Comment: can you provide the full code at jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two issues here, first, even though the stopListen method is called, the event still got posted,

The posted code has syntax errors:

```
> document.removeEventListener "keydown", KeyboardInputManager.prototype.listener
```

should be:

```
document.removeEventListener("keydown", KeyboardInputManager.prototype.listener);
```

Why this doesn't work can't be determined without seeing more code.

> I wanted to call some other prototype methods of A, but the this var in it is the document that is passed to the listener

Because when a function is attached as a listener using *addEventListener*, then *this* within the function is the DOM object that the listener was attached to. If you want some other object, you can set it in the call, e.g.

```
A.prototype.listen = function() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
                                           KeyboardInputManager.prototype.listener.call(A);
                                         });
}
```

However, how you don't have a function to reference to remove the listener. See Suman's answer for ideas on how to fix that (i.e. attached a named function that calls the listener and sets *this* to the value you want).

Answer (score 1):

When you attach the method(`object.methodName`) with `addEventListener()` on particular event, the object would lost when that event will occurred and `this` reference would be global object `document`,

```
function A() {
    console.log("someProperty");
}

A.prototype.newMethod = function () {
    console.log('new method');
}

A.prototype.listener = function () {
    this.newMethod();
}

A.prototype.listen = function() {
    document.addEventListener( "keydown",  callFunc);
}

function callFunc(){
    myObj.listener(); //now inside listener() this refers actual object 
}

A.prototype.stopListen = function() {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", callFunc);
}

var myObj = new A();
myObj.listen();
myObj.stopListen();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruBJ/)